# How to emulate Visual Studio 2010 behavior when running MsTest tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

When you run MsTest tests using Visual Studio 2008 or the command line with default options, the binaries are copied to an "Out" folder. The same doesn't happens when you run it with the Visual Studio 2010. What is the command line options that enable me to achieve the same result as VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the ".testsettings" in the solution items. (Add one if need be.) Edit it, choose "Deployment," then check "Enable deployment." Save the SLN.

Comment: I cited only one of the differences between running the command line and using Visual Studio. I would like to know which command line argument VS uses to obtain a 100% identical behavior.